# Different between pid mem and tid mem

Tags: linux, multithreading, memory-management, pid, proc

What is the difference between `/proc/pid/mem` and `/proc/pid/task/tid` (with same pid)

Both of them including the same data? Or maybe is there any difference?

Comment: A proc can have multiple threads.

Comment: I know that. I ask if both paths include the same data? Is  `/proc/pid/mem` in offset X contains exactly data like `/proc/pid/task/tid` in offset X